# accessing selected request localization culture in MVC Core _Layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

Using standard .net localization middleware:

```cs
var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("en"), new CultureInfo("de") ...
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
   DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en", "en"),
   SupportedCultures = supportedCultures, ...
```

How might I access the language selected, so that in _Layout.cshtml I can add something like:

```html
<html lang="@[????].CultureCode">
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is still exactly the same namespace and properties as the old ASP.NET 4.x days:

```
<html lang="@System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name">
```